# Question About An Time Complexity Example

Tags: time-complexity

I'm new programmer and learning data structure and algorithm recently. Right now I cannot understand a time complexity example from Geeks for Geeks and really appreciate your advice

Here is the link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/
We can refer to part (1) and (2) in the above link

```
   // 1st piece of code  
   for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }

   // 2nd piece of code: and c is a constant  
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c) {
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

I don't know why the 2nd piece of code has O(N) while the first piece has O(1) just because the 2nd piece increases by c, but the first piece increases by a constant (which is one) too. 
If possible, can anyone suggest any resources that I can read so that I can understand time complexity well? Recently I'm doing some practice on HackerRank and a lot of my programs cannot pass all the test cases just because they run slowly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line of complexity analysis is to find a relation between the size of the input and the approximate number of operations an algorithm will perform given that input. The link you provided uses the Big-Oh, an upper bound for the number of operations of an algorithm.
In summary, Big-Oh may be defined as:

```
O(g(n)) = { f(n): there exist positive constants c and n0
          such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n0 }
```

The first loop is executed a constant amount of iterations, independent of the input size. So, f(n) - the function that represents the number of operations your algorithm perform for a input of size n - is affected by a constant. Therefore, you can find another constant c that, when multiplied by 1 (g(n)), will result in a value always bigger than f(n). In a chart, you'll see your f(n) as a horizontal line (it is a constant - it does not change with N).

On the other hand, the second loop depends on the size of N since it determines when the loop ends. Thus, you cannot find a constant that can be multiplied by 1 (g(n)) so that it will always be bigger than f(n). For instance, as your loop depends on the size of n, assume the function f(n) = n. If you initially pick a constant c (c=10), when n >= 11, f(n) > c.g(n), so O(1) does not apply. Of course, you could pick a bigger c, but then, when n > c, it won't apply. The only way to make it works is to have, at least, O(n).

There are some good MOOC on the subject. For instance:
 - https://www.coursera.org/learn/analysis-of-algorithms
 - https://www.courses.com/university-of-new-south-wales/cs2-data-structures-and-algorithms/1

For a list of available MOOCs on the subject: https://medium.com/@codingfreak/best-online-video-courses-for-data-structures-and-algorithms-616a97556de1

https://www.coursera.org/learn/analysis-of-algorithms